# Replacement for Vue 2 'v-on' in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am migrating a Laravel Vue2 & Vuetify2 project to Laravel Vue3/Vuetify3.
I know that **v-on** has been removed. In the Vue2 project, I used the following code to display a tooltip for `<v-btn>`

```
          <v-tooltip top>
             <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                 <v-btn
                     :color="icon3Color"
                     dark
                     fab
                     small
                     v-on="on"
                     @click="createPost()"
                     >
                 <v-icon>add</v-icon>
                 </v-btn>
             </template>
             <span>Post</span>
         </v-tooltip>
```

I am struggling to find its replacement. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "`v-on` has been removed"? It's the Vue event listener syntax; [it's still there in Vue 3](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-on).

Answer (score 2):

In Vuetify 3 v-on with activator slot is still working and available:

[Activator slots](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/accessibility/#activator-slots)

It is also possible for you to use this syntax :

```
<template v-slot:activator="{ on: activationEvents }">
    <v-btn
       :color="icon3Color"
       dark
       fab
       small
       v-on="activationEvents"
       @click="createPost()"
     >
     <v-icon>add</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is able to display tooltips for my buttons:

```
 <v-btn :color="icon3Color"  fab small @click="createPost()">
    <v-icon>mdi-plus</v-icon>
    <v-tooltip activator="parent" location="top">Create Post</v-tooltip>
 </v-btn>
```